# How to write a parameterized SQL query in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, parameterized

how to write a parameterized SQL Query in javascript ?

i am trying this but getting an error

i am also tried this 2 still getting syntax error

**let sql =`select * from q_users where firstname=?,[${name}]`;**

**let sql =`select * from q_users where firstname=?,${name}`;**

```
let sql =`select * from q_users where firstname=?,${[name]}`;
db.query(sql)
.then((data)=>{
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to just stick to the [extensive documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries) - and learning basic javascript. The statement

```
let sql =`select * from q_users where firstname=?,${[name]}`;
```

makes no sense, it's just a string with an array at its end. It might be helpful to read up about [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to get to know them and how to use them properly.

The docs explain to pass two arguments to `db.query()`. So you will need something like

```
let sql = 'select * from q_users where firstname=?';
db.query(sql, [name]).then(...);
```

Also, avoid using `name` as a variable's name.

Comment: but sometimes i have different parameters length then how can i handle dynamic ?

like 

let sql = 'select * from q_users where firstname=?';
db.query(sql, [name]).then(...);

let sql = 'select * from q_users where firstname=? and lastname=?';
db.query(sql, [name,lname]).then(...);

here i don't want to reWrite db.query()

Comment: You'd obviously pass a single array. db.query(sql, [param1, param2, param3]). @AjayKumbhare ... Again, the docs have all your questions covered in detail