# How to put fully string content in js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

so i have this block of sql query code here for sending user description to db in node js.

```
const sqlAddDescription = (desc, id) => {return `UPDATE \`Memcon\`.\`users_list\` SET \`description\` = '${desc}' WHERE (\`id\` = '${id}')`}
```

it's working completely fine, in the client user inputs a text and the db process goes on with no problem.

BUT if the user sends an input with backticks or quotes or even brackets, the process gonna fail because their text head on goes to ${desc} and it replaces it, so it creates an error.

How can i tell js to fully stringify the text, no matter the inputs.

(i also tried JSON.stringify but that serves a different purpose )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript string replace with regex to strip off illegal characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780696/javascript-string-replace-with-regex-to-strip-off-illegal-characters)

Comment: Use parameterized query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840094/how-to-write-a-parameterized-sql-query-in-javascript